# Django: Django-Registration Password Reset Error

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I just installed the Django-Registration app and I have everything working except I can not figure out the password reset methods. Whenever I navigate to accounts/password/reset/ I get the following error:

Reverse for 'password_reset_done' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
Any ideas? Is there some problems with the django-registration urls?

Update:

I have added the following lines of code from a previous post here: Django 1.6 and django-registration: built-in authentication views not picked up

into my registration/backends/default/urls.py

```
url(r'^password/change/$',
                           auth_views.password_change,
                           name='password_change'),
                       url(r'^password/change/done/$',
                           auth_views.password_change_done,
                           name='password_change_done'),
                       url(r'^password/reset/$',
                           auth_views.password_reset,
                           name='password_reset'),
                       url(r'^password/reset/done/$',
                           auth_views.password_reset_done,
                           name='password_reset_done'),
                       url(r'^password/reset/complete/$',
                           auth_views.password_reset_complete,
                           name='password_reset_complete'),
                       url(r'^password/reset/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$',
                           auth_views.password_reset_confirm,
                           name='password_reset_confirm'),

                      #and now add the registration urls
                       url(r'', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
```

and then I added the following import:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
```

But then when I run the program after my server restart I get the following error message:

> Exception Type: RuntimeError Exception Value: maximum recursion depth
>   exceeded while calling a Python object Exception Location:
>   /home/ubuntu/django-skippl/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.2-
>   py2.7.egg/django/utils/datastructures.py in init, line 287 Python
>   Executable: /home/ubuntu/django-skippl/bin/python

Answer (score 0):

try this urls.py

```
import os

from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),

    #override the default urls
    url(r'^password/change/$',
                auth_views.password_change,
                name='password_change'),
    url(r'^password/change/done/$',
                auth_views.password_change_done,
                name='password_change_done'),
    url(r'^password/reset/$',
                auth_views.password_reset,
                name='password_reset'),
    url(r'^password/reset/done/$',
                auth_views.password_reset_done,
                name='password_reset_done'),
    url(r'^password/reset/complete/$',
                auth_views.password_reset_complete,
                name='password_reset_complete'),
    url(r'^password/reset/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$',
                auth_views.password_reset_confirm,
                name='password_reset_confirm'),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is should work :

```
url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.simple.urls')),

url(r'^accounts/password/reset/done/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_done',
   name='password_reset_done'),
```